# iOS bind images in array and on the disk

Tags: ios, nsarray

I have NSArray that contains UIImage objects. When I add new image to this array I also save the same image on disk. It is work ok for me.

When I remove image from the NSArray I also want to remove this image from the disk.

So if use for example index 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 it is not good for me to store images on the disk.

Let me show why:

So for example I create images 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 (I remove .png just keep with indexes).

Second step is remove third element in my array, So I know that the index for removing element is 2 because it is third in array.

I remove image with appropriate index name on the disk.

So how can I bind my images on the disk and in the array.

Maybe another solution I think can be add counter that will every time increase count of image for get unique name id and also using names of file instead of indexes of UIImage in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an additional NSDictionary. You could use an NSString as the key that contains a unique identifier for each image (which you also use as the filename), and the UIImage as the value. Then, your array could store the NSStrings with the ids.

So for example:

```
NSMutableArray *array = @[@"a", @"b", @"c"];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = @{@"a" : firstImage,
                                    @"b" : secondImage,
                                    @"c" : thirdImage,};
```

So, to get the `secondImage` you would do

```
UIImage *secondImage = dictionary[array[1]];
```

If you then remove that image (and dictionary, you need to keep them synched), your array will look like this [@"a", @"c"]. Executing the line above will return `thirdImage` this time.

Your filenames could should be a.png, b.png and c.png. So you also have that.

I hope that helps!

Comment: ok first of all the I get images via camera uiimagedatapicker so I don't know about id or file name.

So I solved this issue by writing my solution, So first time I save image as "0.jpg", so second time I look into the folder and grab all files from it. Then I remove extension and path from files name and get only one digital '0' from each file. then I start compare all digital and find max. Max digital I increase by adding + 1. So and right now I store only file names instead of uiimage in my array and can create and remove the images on the disk using paths.